# Breaking UTF-16 Unicode text by delimiters in Applescript?

Tags: unicode, applescript

I have a list of text coded in MacRoman, broken by linefeeds. Somehow a second list could not be saved in MacRoman, so I had to use Unicode UTF-16 to get German "ö", "ä" and stuff. While ListA gets filled like expected, listB doesn't get broken anymore and I end up with a single string, which I'm unable to break anymore/don't know how. Can someone help me out?

```
set ListA to (read file myFile1 using delimiter linefeed) as list    
display dialog "" & item 1 of ListA    
--> "Name A" 

set ListB to (read file myFile2 using delimiter linefeed as Unicode text) as list    
display dialog "" & item 1 of ListB    
--> "Name A    
Name B    
Name C    
Name D"
```

Answer (score 1):

There can be many different types of characters that separate lines in text files. It's not always a linefeed. The easiest way to handle them is with the applescript command "paragraphs" rather than using the delimiter when reading the file. Paragraphs is pretty good at figuring out what character is used and handling it. It doesn't always work but it's worth a try before you go any deeper into the problem. As such, try reading your files like this...

```
set ListB to paragraphs of (read file myFile2 as Unicode text)
```

If that doesn't work then you'll have to try and figure out what the character is. What I do in these cases is physically open the file and select the return character with my mouse... and copy it. Then I go back to AppleScript Editor and paste it into this command.  Paste it where I have the letter "a". It will give you the character id.

```
id of "a"
```

Then you can read the file using the delimiter like this, obviously using the id number from the command above in place of 97...

```
set ListB to read file myFile2 using delimiter (character id 97) as Unicode text
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the file uses LF line endings? This works for me:

```
set f to POSIX file "/tmp/1"
set b to open for access f with write permission
set eof b to 0
write "あ" & linefeed & "い" to b as Unicode text -- UTF-16
close access b
read f using delimiter linefeed as Unicode text
```

Did you try saving the file as UTF-8? You can read it by replacing `Unicode text` with `«class utf8»`.